# I want to restrict the input of special characters in url with rewrite module

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

This is the code in the Apache conf file.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\.|%2e%2e|%252e%252e|%u002e%u002e) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\.|^%2e%2e|^%252e%252e|^%u002e%u002e)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /err_page.php [L]
```

What should I change?

Comment: What "special characters" and where (URL-path _and_ query string)? Why? It maybe easier to just allow the specific characters you require and reject the rest?

Comment: You should not try to reinvent the wheel. Use mod_security to block a wide variety of attacks, including those you haven't yet seen.